# Multi threading in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service class that makes a number of asyncronous ajax calls using forkJoin, maps all of the responses to a class, caches that class and returns an Observable of that class. If the data is in the cache, it then skips the ajax call and just returns the data from the cache. It can take 15+ secs to run for some requests.  If the function needs to make the ajax calls, it sets a boolean "loading" property on the service class.

The service is injected as a singleton in to a number of components. I'd like that when a call is made to the method and the loading is already in progress, that call "waits" for the loading thread to complete and then gets the cached value.  However, I'm having difficulty getting the one thread to wait.  I've tried while(loading) {setTimeout(...)}, but the entire system freezes.  I've also tried calling the method recursively, but it quickly reaches the maximum number of calls on the stack.

What is the best strategy for handling this issue?

Comment: Async or Service Workers.

Comment: If you're using observables, why can't you just subscribe and let that method get called when your service has finished doing its work?